# Using AWS in an Android app and running my own Python server on AWS

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, networking

I've built my Android app and it's nearly done and now I have decided that I'd like to store the Python server I wrote on an AWS server.
Till now the server ran on the same network as the Android app and I connected them with a TCP socket. The server and client work perfectly fine together as long as they're in the same private network.

I tried changing the IP in the socket definition to the public IPv4 of the AWS server I launched and changing the port to the listening port that's defined in the server's code but it couldn't connect.

The server I launched on AWS is EC2 with Ubuntu.

The connection methods I used before:

```
    Connection(){ //a c'tor of the Connection class
        serverIP = IP_CONST;
        serverPort = PORT_CONST;

        try{
            serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown host", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            connectionError = true;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        isTheServerFree = false;

        try {
            if (!connectionError) {
                socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }

            if (socket == null){
                connectionError = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            connectionError = true;
        }

        isTheServerFree = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the AWS instance's firewall and/or iptables.

Comment: So the connection method I've used on my client can reach out to public IP's as well?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And how can I change the instance's firewall settings or iptables? I also tried now to change the connection method of the server to TCP from SSH since I connect the client with a TCP socket but still nothing happened.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on IP, TCP, Wireshark, and how to debug networking problems. There is a lot you have yet to learn. For your specific situation, this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-python-web-app-on-aws-57ed772b2319) may be a good starting point.